# Change string to objectId within json in pymongo+flask and insert it into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using Swagger+pymongo and I wanted something really simple to convert a `string` into an `ObjectId`. How can I do this very easily without touching other db schemas.(Minimal effort)?

Code:

```
jsonResponse = request.json['business']
# convert business_id Datatype to ObjectId
business_id=ObjectId(jsonResponse['business_id'])

#add business_id (ObjectId)to mongodb
data = collection.insert_one(jsonResponse).inserted_id
return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = request.json['business']
response_oid = ObjectId(response['business_id'])

mongo_item = response.copy()
mongo_item['business_id'] = response_oid

return collection.insert_one(mongo_item).inserted_id
```

Should do the job.